# Execute a Toast message inside a setOnCheckedChangeListener method

Tags: java, android, actionlistener, toast

I have an array of togglebuttons.  There is a 1-to-1 ratio of toggleButtons with number of rows in a cursor.  I assign an setId() to each toggleButton in the array with returned data from the cursor.

My update is always updating 1 row up in the cursor and I'm trying to troubleshoot this issue using some toast messages.  The problem is that I can't get the toast message to display.  I know the method is listener is firing because my sql update is running, it's just that it's the wrong row.  Here is my code.

```
toggleButton[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //Create the new content values object for data input
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
            {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Cart.this.getBaseContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    toggleButton[buttonView.getId()].setTextOn("Yes"); //Set the text when the button changes state to on
                    values.put(Contract.ItemsTable.COLUMN_ONE, 1); //Update the record on the 'status' column to true
                    String[] itemId = {String.valueOf(buttonView.getId())}; //
                    db.update(Contract.ItemsTable.TABLE_NAME, values, SmartCartContract.ItemsTable.COLUMN_ITEM_ID + " LIKE ?", itemId); //Update the DB record
                } else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Cart.this.getBaseContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    toggleButton[buttonView.getId()].setTextOff("No"); //Set the text when the button changes state to off
                    values.put(SmartCartContract.ItemsTable.COLUMN_TWO, 0); //Update the record on the 'status' column to false
                    String[] itemId = {String.valueOf(buttonView.getId())}; //
                    db.update(Contract.ItemsTable.TABLE_NAME, values, Contract.ItemsTable.COLUMN_ITEM_ID + " LIKE ?", itemId); //Update the DB record
                }
            }
        });
```

Cart.this.getBaseContext() is my last attempt of the options I've seen to use.  Is this what I'm doing wrong?

I'm building those buttons dynamically with:

```
toggleButton[i] = new ToggleButton(this); //Create new ToggleButton control for this row    
toggleButton[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); //Align the text in the middle 
toggleButton[i].setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("itemId"))); 
if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("itemInCart")) == 1) //Check if marked 'in Cart'
```

Comment: You could just toast the isChecked value immediately, no reason to copy the same line twice

Comment: @cricket_007 - thanks for the reply.  I actually had it there and it wasn't firing too.  I moved it inside just to troubleshoot and then I created the post

Comment: Also, I'm not looking for the boolean value.  That part is working (assigning of the 0 and the 1).  I'm updating the wrong row in the db, not the wrong value in the column.

Comment: Are you sure you want `buttonView.getId()`? That returns the id of the button in the XML as an int. In which case for SQL, you wouldn't use `LIKE` to compare integers

Comment: thanks @cricket_007.  That's interesting.  Because I'm building those buttons dynamically with:

    toggleButton[i] = new ToggleButton(this); //Create new ToggleButton control for this row
            toggleButton[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); //Align the text in the middle
            toggleButton[i].setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("itemId")));
            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("itemInCart")) == 1) //Check if marked 'in Cart'

and in this case my cursor has 5 rows.  toast shows 1,2,3,4 and 5 which maps to the ItemId in the DB.  Am I way off here?

Comment: Okay, so you have dynamic views. That's what was missing from my understanding, though `setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("itemId")))` and `toggleButton[buttonView.getId()]` don't look like the same id/index pairing

Comment: so I basically set the id of the toggleButon with setId(passing itemId from db) which gives the toggleButton[index] the ID of the item.  It looks like I'm doing that.  I guess what you're saying is that they are getting the id in the xml as an int. There is no xml for those buttons, so if I didn't set the id like i am doing now, how would those buttons get an id like you said (with no xml)

Comment: Right, forget the XML comment. I meant the index of the array should be different than the index of the column in the database (or that column value) for most of the buttons

Comment: and I did a test, I set the id with setID(itemID + 10) and each button was tagged as 11,12,13,14 and 15 as the toast message just showed that.  I'm so confused.  It really comes down to the db.update call.  for some reason when I think I'm clicking toggleButton.id=4, it updates db.itemId=3.  and so on.  Also, interestingly if I hard code a value say like 33 (which doesn't exist) and I click the 3rd button in the group, it updates db.id #2.  I'm so confused because I thought this was working in an earlier commit.

Comment: If I have one item in the db, it has an ID of 1.  When I build the list of buttons, index[0] will have an id of 1, because I'm setting that with the DB.item.Id.  So, when that 1 and only button is clicked, with my code, the query tries to update item.ID = 0 in the DB.  that is what is confusing me.  If I hard code 10 like this:  String[] itemId = {String.valueOf(10)};, it still tries to update Db.Item.ID = 0.

Comment: Okay, I suppose I trust your testing process.... Like I said earlier, though, you are using `LIKE` instead of `=`, so maybe that's an issue

Comment: Moved the Toast message outside and it doesn't fire.  Using = now instead of ? and still the same thing.  If I just get that toast message to come up or some how log those values to the console.  The part that really has me is even when hard coding the update value, it's still just updating the wrong row in the cursor by 1.

Comment: @cricket_007 - thanks for helping me on this.

Comment: Instead of toast, just use Log.d. I'm assuming you are using the emulator.

Comment: I'm not using an emulator.  Those are painful even with the BIOS/hardware emulation settings on with a strong laptop/desktop.  I just deploy each time to physical hardware.

Comment: Try using `mContext` instead of `Cart.this.getBaseContext()`, with `private Context mContext = this;` at class variable declaration (I mean before `onCreate(...)` for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the problem with the database is, but here is a minimal example of some `ToggleButtons` with a working Toast.

```
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        ContentValues cv;

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            cv = new ContentValues();
            String key;
            int val;

            if (isChecked) {
                key = "col1";
                val = 1;
            } else {
                key = "col2";
                val = 0;
            }

            cv.put(key, val);
            String[] itemId = {String.valueOf(buttonView.getId())};
            Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this,
                    String.format("[%d] %s {%s}", buttonView.getId(), isChecked, cv),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(this);
        view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ToggleButton[] buttons = new ToggleButton[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            ToggleButton toggle = new ToggleButton(this);

            toggle.setLayoutParams(lp);
            toggle.setId(i);
            toggle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);            
            toggle.setTextOn(String.format("On [%d]", i));
            toggle.setTextOff(String.format("Off [%d]", i));
            toggle.setChecked(false);
            toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);

            buttons[i] = toggle;
            view.addView(toggle);
        }

        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting that @cricket_007.  I'll try it today.  Do you know if the code sniplets fully work? With my code above, I set my text to be "YES" and "NO" but when the buttons are clicked, they change to "ON" and "OFF" which is the default.

Comment: I copy pasted this straight from Android Studio. You should only need to add the Activity of the Manifest

Comment: Welcome. Of course, you'll still need to put the database back in, but at least the Toast works. If the Toast still doesn't work, you could  `Log.d()` to print to the logcat

Comment: I'm not implementing the ActionListeners the same way that you are.  I have one for each toggleButton in the array.  I can't have it up in the class declarations like you also.  Unfortunately in this case I can't use this way, although I tried the code in another test project.

Comment: You are welcome to make an anonymous class. I just find it cleaner to write the way that I did for this simple example. And my listener has the exact same functionality as yours. You do not need a new listener for each button.

Comment: Well interestingly the db update is now working and updating the correct row, but I haven't changed anything.  I wonder if not recycling/closing a cursor could cause erroneous errors?  Anyway, it's working now and when I can get the toast to run, I'll close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of object Cart is. But you could extend the Application class and save off the application context, which you could then use in your toasts.

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

public class BaseApplication extends Application
{
    protected static Context context;
    protected static PackageInfo packageInfo;
    protected static BaseApplication baseApplication;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        try
            {

                baseApplication = this;

                context = getApplicationContext();

                PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
                String packageName = context.getPackageName();

                packageInfo = manager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
                // ignore
            }
    }

    public static Context getContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    public static PackageInfo getPackageInfo()
    {
        return packageInfo;
    }

    public static BaseApplication getApplication(){
        return baseApplication;
    }
}
```

Comment: public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: Maybe I'm going down a pigeon hole.  The real issue is that I'm updating the wrong row by one position in the cursor and I'm trying to see why.

Comment: I tried that also with no luck.  I even tried Cart.this.getBase

Comment: How does this help the toast anymore than `getApplicationContext()` alone?

Comment: @cricket_007 - is that question for me or dvallejo?

Comment: For you. I think creating an extension of the Application class is a bit overkill

Comment: My class doesn't extend Application (I didn't write that above).  My class
public class Authorizations extends AppCompatActivity